# How to handle google one tap with laravel csrf

Tags: php, laravel, post, csrf, google-one-tap

I tried adding [google one tap](https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/web/guides/display-google-one-tap) on a laravel app.

```
    <div id="g_id_onload"
         data-client_id="{{ config('google.google_client_id') }}"
         data-login_uri="{{ route('google2.callback') }}"
         _token="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    </div>
```

But I still get a `419 PAGE EXPIRED` with a `CSRF Token mismatch` exception with and without the `_token` parameter.
How should I handle this on the post route?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone with this problem the issue is that every parameter must be preceded by `data-`
so it has to be:

```
 <div id="g_id_onload"
         data-client_id="{{ config('google.google_client_id') }}"
         data-login_uri="{{ route('google2.callback') }}"
         data-_token="{{ csrf_token() }}">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

[how to add google one tap login in laravel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LkYdu.png)

You can send the csrf token like this.
Here is a detailed instruction showing on adding one tap login to laravel app.
https://teachnep.com/blog/how-to-add-one-tap-login-to-laravel-project